# control multiple vnc server using one client

Tags: vnc, remote, kali

So. I'm searching a way to control multiple vnc server which have the dame settings and the same resolution with only one vnc client . The goal is to acheive batch operation to do exactly the same thing.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you are having?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: Well the specifics are going to depend on what VNC client you are using and whether you are tunneling the connections.

Comment: Which client could do this, I'm not tunneling the connection